Does this Raven's matrix of white and black squares have a unique solution?
This puzzle was generated with the software Corvus, developed for the program author's PhD thesis. Supposedly, the software only outputs items with unique solutions. However, it seems to me the solution can be either a white square or a black square: A white square, if the rule is XOR from left-to-right (and top-to-bottom), or a black square, if the rule is an increasing diagonal of white squares, or simply either if the rule is preserving symmetry along the decreasing diagonal.
Cells with paper taped over them are supposed to be "concealed" cells; you don't know what they contain.


Or it could be a grey square, where the rule is that each row/column contains one of each colour.

I feel that alternative is less problematic as it's not implied by the matrix alone.

What is the blue background part? Options for "?" or something else? Also; you ignore displayed variations in border color and size, which may help create a single obvious solution (which I don't see).

The most obvious thing I see is that symbols are identical on "/" diagonals with wrap-around.  That means the ? would be anything you find below the concealed R2C3 and R3C2.  So it could be anything.  If I had to guess, I would say the gray square, as other suggest, because it makes the diagonals more visible.

If it had a slightly different alternative...

 ...a grey square (with white/invisible edge) then that would fit very well. ? would be a grey square with white edge, center would be a white square with black edge, middle-right would be a grey square with white edge, bottom-middle would be a grey square with white edge.

Because

 Horizontally and vertically the color of the edges and the color inside the squares would alternate between white, grey and black.

The closest to that answer is

 The grey square with black edge, however it's not as satisfying as the alternative I had in mind.


Astute observation!
